# Increase Game Speed when Recording

Tags: windows-8, memory, performance, graphics, gaming

First of all, here are the specs of my pc.

- Intel Dual Core CPU 2.68 GHz with 64 bit architecture
- 4 GB DDR3 ram with two 2 GB cards
- NVIDIA GeForce 210 SILENT 1GB DDR3 Graphics Card
- Windows 8 Pro 32 bit OS

I just wanted to record my game play of Spider-Man 3 game with ZDSoft Screen Recorder 5.2 Pro version. The game runs fine with a capping of 30 fps but when I press record, the fps drops to 20 so my game appears a bit choppy. I'm recording at 1280x720 resolution though the game runs at 1400x900 resolution.

I tried using GameBooster but when GameBooster is in the system tray, the recorder won't record. I've also tried using the recorder within GameBooster but it is more slower than the zdsoft's one.

Though before recording, I'm closing all the apps and cleaning with CCleaner.

What can I do to increase the fps when recording?

Thanks.

Comment: Try FRAPS. I prefer it over other "game-recording" softwares.

Comment: But I've already purchased ZDSoft's one.

Comment: Fraps demo version is performing more drastically than zdsoft pro.

Comment: Try lowering the settings of the game.  Sounds like your computer cannot handle both recording and the game itself..  You have a very weak computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types of video capture software can be quite demanding on your PC. They take screenshots for every frame per second and often do some encoding on the fly. They will always reduce the performance of the game you are trying to play. The only thing you can do is try turning the graphics settings down in game when you want to record. This will give you a higher FPS when not recording but will then drag you back down a little when you start recording again. The downfall to this obviously is that the graphics of the game will not look at good in the video.

Comment: I've uploaded one video after reducing the texture quality. Does it look smooth enough? Here's it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5aE0c638qE Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't look too bad. It depends on what you want it for though. I am guessing you are just going to post some youtube videos of some gameplay as a bit of a hobby. This is fine for that sort of thing but you know you can always improve your videos and the only way really would be to upgrade your PC. That is why alot of streamers have some really high spec pcs even though they are playing some pretty low spec games like League of Legends. You could also look into trying a few different programs like others have advised to see if you can get a bit better FPS but you wont get a lot more.

Comment: I'm just leaving this since I'm just uploading as a hobby. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are various ways of increasing your recording speed, however before I jump into those, what do you mean by "choppy"? Do you mean the game as you see it is choppy or the recorded file is choppy? On some demanding games, the game may seem sluggish while recording but the output file is perfectly smooth.

Are you running a SSD or HDD? Recording to a HDD, especially a slow one, can lead to horrible performance loss, as the program has little time to write data to disk and has to reduce the rate at which it can record.

Another solution is to try other software and to see which one performs better. I personally prefer FRAPS, however it's up to you to determine which one you want to use. Considering you already bought ZDSoft's, this may not be a viable solution.

You could also check in your game settings if there is a way to run at full FPS, which can help in some cases. I had to record a game on a mediocre computer once and disabling VSync and FPS capping helped my recorder pick up a higher number of frames.

While recording, make sure you kill useless background tasks which may consume processing power. Closing your browser and closing off anything you don't need can help you gain some performance.

Ultimately, you could upgrade hardware. The issue could be either with the processor or the GPU here, since both aren't really all that powerful.

I'm afraid there's not much more you can do aside from that, try them and see if they help you. I'm just suggesting things I have used successfully in the past.